# Tensorflow Minimal Multilayer Perceptron has Inconsistent Convergence

Tags: tensorflow

### Why is my convergence inconsistent (how to fix)?

I wanted to test a simple multi-layer perceptron on an XOR problem set. I didn't split the training set, so I was expecting to get 100% accuracy, but after 2000 epochs I find the model is still often making mistakes

This is my first tf estimator, so I figure I'm missing something simple. The tensorflow docs seem to use a different method of structuring estimators so I haven't had much luck figuring it out from their

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from itertools import product
import numpy as np

# Data
X = np.array(list(product([0,1], repeat=3)))
y = np.array([a ^ b ^ c for a, b, c in X])

# Define the Model
INPUT_UNITS = 3
HIDDEN_LAYER_UNITS  = 5
OUTPUT_UNITS = 2

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Input(INPUT_UNITS))
model.add(layers.Dense(HIDDEN_LAYER_UNITS, tf.nn.relu))
model.add(layers.Dense(HIDDEN_LAYER_UNITS, tf.nn.relu))
model.add(layers.Dense(HIDDEN_LAYER_UNITS, tf.nn.relu))
model.add(layers.Dense(OUTPUT_UNITS, tf.nn.softmax))

# Train 
N_EPOCHS = 2000
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Nadam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(x=X,  
    epochs=N_EPOCHS, 
    y=y,
    verbose=0)

model.evaluate(X, y)

predicted = np.argmax(model.predict(x=X), axis=1)
print(f"Predicted: {predicted}")
print(f"Actual: {y}")
```

It also strikes me that 2000 epochs seems like an awfully high number given a domain size of 8. But 200 epochs almost never reaches 100% accuracy

Comment: I ran your model, majority of the times the model converges to an accuracy of 1 after ~400 epochs.

Comment: It seems like a really simple problem for it to ever get stuck on. There's only 8 samples in the first place